# Newman's modularity clustering for graphs

Tags: clustering, networks, partitioning, igraph, modularity

I am interested in running Newman's [modularity clustering](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1482622/) algorithm on a large graph. If you can point me to a library (or R package, etc) that implements it I would be most grateful.

Comment: sorry for the graphical-techniques tag, but my brand new account doesn't let me tag with 'graph' and 'partitioning' as I intended to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [igraph](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/index.html) library implements some algorithms for community structure based on Newman's optimization of modularity.  You can consult the [reference manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/igraph/igraph.pdf) for details and citations.

Answer (score 6):

Use the igraph package for R:
http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/fastgreedy.community.html
this implements a fast algorithm for community finding using the newman-girvan modularity maximization method.

your code will look like this:

```
library(igraph)
# read graph from csv file
G<-read.graph("unipartite_edgelist.txt", format="ncol")
fgreedy<-fastgreedy.community(G,merges=TRUE, modularity=TRUE)
memberships <-community.to.membership(G, fgreedy$merges, steps=which.max(fgreedy$modularity)-1)
print(paste('Number of detected communities=',length(memberships$csize)))
    # Community sizes:
    print(memberships$csize)
# modularity:
max(fgreedy$modularity)
```